# Cannot reach daily rep limit by upvote if I've been un-upvoted and re-upvoted

Tags: feature-request, upvotes, daily-reputation-limit

I don't want to seem like a rep-fiend, but I do get a sense of satisfaction out of reaching that daily 200 rep from upvotes alone. Today, I got 20 new upvotes, but also 2 "unupvotes" and what I assume are "reupvotes" (they are on the same old posts, and in close succession):

[image]

So in total, I got 180 rep from 18 new upvotes, and it seems that *technically*, I got 20 rep from the "unupvote / reupvote" posts. However, I also got 2 other upvotes from new posts, but these don't get counted :(

Just wondering if there is any way this scenario could *eventually* be accounted for? I see how it could be pretty complicated to implement :/

(Note: Just to be clear, I'm not asking to get extra rep for today! Just wanted to point out this behaviour and see how possible people think this would be (or if it would be a good idea at all))

Comment: So if you were upvoted on a day that you hit the rep cap, and someone unupvoted and re-voted on a day that you didn't rep cap, you'd expect to not have your reputation change?

Comment: Yeah, it would be complicated to implement I suppose...

Comment: Pretty normal, somebody accidenti-clicked.  They normally filter those, but there was a major problem this morning that forced them to queue back 20 million delayed rep updates.  Surely connected to this mishap.

Comment: @HansPassant, huh... so I guess they usually filter those by the time elapsed between un-upvote and re-upvote?

Comment: Must be nice to work in a tag where even *approaching* the limit is possible. I feel wonderful if I can rake together 100 points in a week...

Answer (score 7):

I think it's entirely reasonable to say that if someone retracts a vote, and then re-casts it at some point later, the new vote is considered to be cast when it was actually cast, and not treated as if it was cast whenever the first time the user voted on that post was.  Mostly because that's just *super* complicated to try to explain to anyone, is so rarely relevant to anyone, and in the rare cases that it is, it's not problematic that it behaves the way that it does.